# ReactJS : Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While calling  `useEffect` function on one of my submethod result in

> ReactJS : Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component.

The Flow

`onClick(message) --> call CallGetAMIDetails(message) --> Call Loaddata(message) --> Perform REST Call  and -->Returns Array of String`

But my class is already a function component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {DashboardLayout} from '../components/Layout';
import Select from 'react-select'


const options = [
    {value: 'ami-abc*', label: 'ami-abc'},
    {value: 'ami-xyz*', label: 'ami-xyz'},
]



const DiscoverAMIPage = () => {

    function Loaddata() {
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
        const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
        const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
            fetch("http://localhost:10000/connections")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(
                    (result) => {
                        setIsLoaded(true);
                        setItems(result);
                    },
                    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
                    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
                    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
                    (error) => {
                        setIsLoaded(true);
                        setError(error);
                    }
                )
        }, [])

        if (error) {
            return []
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return []
        } else {
            return (
                items
            );
        }
    }

    function CallGetAMIDetails(message) {
        return Loaddata(message)

    }

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Discovered AMI</h2>
    <Select
    onChange={e => {
        setMessage(e.value);
        setItems(CallGetAMIDetails(e.value));
    }}
    options={options}
    />
    {console.log("----")}
    <h2>{items}</h2>
    {console.log("----")}

    </DashboardLayout>
)
}

export default DiscoverAMIPage;
```

[image: Error Message]

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: I think due to `Loaddata` being called react does not consider it to be a component, but a regular JS function. See [Only call hooks from react functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Comment: The error tells you what you're doing - hooks can only be called at the "top level" of component functions, but you're calling useEffect() in the Loaddata() function, which is not the top level of your DiscoverAMI component

Comment: I'll be clear. that is happening bcuz you have ´Loaddata´ inside ´DiscoverAMIPage´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `Loaddata`.  You're confusing *components* with *normal functions* and trying to use them interchangeably, which is leading to a drastically over-engineered and broken structure.

`DiscoverAMIPage` is your component.  Inside that component should be your calls to `useState` and `useEffect`.  The `useState` calls define your component's state values and the `useEffect` call invokes an operation when dependencies change on a re-render.  Simplify what you're doing.

For example:

```
const DiscoverAMIPage = () => {

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:10000/connections")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setItems(result);
                },
                // Note: it's important to handle errors here
                // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
                // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error);
                }
            )
    }, [])

    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Discovered AMI</h2>
            <Select
                onChange={e => setMessage(e.value)}
                options={options}
            />
            <h2>{items}</h2>
        </DashboardLayout>
    );
}
```

Now you have a component with 4 state values and 1 effect.  That effect is that an AJAX operation is performed when the component is first loaded (and never again afterward), and that operation updates the state when it's complete.  That state update will re-render the component with its new data.  From this starting point you can continue to develop your features.

---

**Edit:** Based on comments below it sounds like you also want to manually invoke the AJAX function in an event handler.  For that you would extract the AJAX logic into a function and invoke that function in both the event handler and in `useEffect`, the same way you would extract functionality into a function to call from multiple places anywhere else.

For example:

```
const loadData = () =>
    fetch("http://localhost:10000/connections")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setItems(result);
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            }
        );

useEffect(loadData, []);
```

Now that you have a function which independently performs the AJAX operation (and `useEffect` is just calling that function), you can call that function in your event handler:

```
<Select
    onChange={e => {
        setMessage(e.value);
        loadData();
    }}
    options={options}
/>
```

If you need to pass the selected value to `loadData` then you can pass `e.value` just like you do to `setMessage`.  Then in `loadData` you'd add a function argument and use it however you need to.

Comment: Many Many thanks, David for helping and teaching me,  I need to call the LoadData or equivalent for every change  on the method with the option selected. The snippet really helps to understand the concept, if you can point me to right direction how to call with it

Comment: @anish: Clarify what it is you need to do.  "I need to call LoadData" doesn't mean anything in this code because there is no such function, and "with the option selected" doesn't mean anything in your original code because no value was ever passed to LoadData.  When the `<Select>` value changes, what specifically do you need to do?

Comment: The user will select the Selection/Dropdown. This selection will pass to function call and return the response. The result will get displayed in the UI using the code you have shown. I'm just confused badly on Functional components and functions. I have update the code. My apologies for troubling you

Comment: @anish: I've updated the answer with an example of how you might do that.  Basically just extract the AJAX operation into a function and call that function where you need to.  In the `useEffect`, in the `change` handler, wherever the component needs to call it.

Comment: You are genenous.